# How to make an Iter from a Map?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to decorate an existing iterator:

```
use std::slice::Iter;

fn only_friend_names(i: Iter<Person>) -> Iter<String> {
  i.filter(|p| p.is_my_friend()).map(|p| p.name())
}
```

It doesn't compile. What do I miss at the end?

BTW, I don't want to collect the data into a vector (for performance reasons) and I do want to return `Iter` (not another type, for compatibility reasons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rust, iterators work by providing a common interface through the `Iterator` trait, and each concrete iterator has its own type. For instance, the `.map(...)` method of an iterator will return a [`Map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html). In particular, this means you *can't* return `Iter<String>`, because that's just not what `.map(...)` returns. Usually, one doesn't care about the actual type of the iterator, so type erasure is fine:

```rust
fn only_friend_names(i: impl Iterator<Item=Person>) -> impl Iterator<Item=String> {
  i.filter(|p| p.is_my_friend()).map(|p| p.name())
}
```

This is both more general (because it will accept any iterators, not just iterators over slices) and you don't have to bother spelling the exact type of the iterator, which can be quite verbose. You probably also want to apply similar transformations to the rest of your code so that returning `Iter<String>` is no longer required.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I can't store the returned value into a struct (or I just don't know how to do it right), but thanks anyway!

Comment: You can store it in a generic `struct Foo<I: Iterator<Item=String>> { names: I }` with `Foo { names: only_friend_names(people) }`. In general, though, it is simpler to collect into a Vec for storing with `struct Foo{ names: Vec<String> }` and `Foo { names: only_friend_names(people).collect() }`.